# Can I distribute instructions on how to extract a private key?

Tags: decryption, law

I'm writing an open-source node.js library that lets people control some hardware, mostly for use in home automation systems. The messages to and from the hardware are AES encrypted, but I was able to find the private key embedded in their Android app.

I know I can't distribute the key along with my app, but generally speaking, can I provide end users with instructions on how to get the key themselves?

I was thinking either being vague (e.g. download the APK, decompile it, find the key in there), or being a little more specific (e.g. download the APK, decompile it with XYZ, look in /src/com/example/lib/keys.java) or perhaps somewhere inbetween (e.g. download the APK, decompile it, do a string search for "private key =")

I understand that Stack Exchange is not a lawyer, but I'm not seeing much on Google to aid me in my research, and wondered if anyone here had some generic advice. I'm in Australia, but advice from anywhere would be helpful.

Comment: Please post your question to http://law.stackexchange.com/ instead, or better yet, talk with a lawyer directly.

Comment: @JasonGeffner I looked at http://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic but felt that my question didn't belong there. Then I saw the "law" tag here, which states that "This tag is for questions relating to legality and not about ethics. If using this tag, then please add details about your location such as state or country". Yes my question isn't directly about reverse engineering as per the help center, but it's a reverse-engineering based topic (I RE'd an app to get the private key), hence why I posted my question here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the wording for the `law` tag. [I've now updated it.](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/law/info)

Answer (score 0):

IIRC in Australia it is completely legal to reverse engineer code for "compatibility" purposes, with some caveats (e.g. source must not be available from the vendor and you must have legally purchased a copy you reverse).

You can describe the procedure in full, just don't include the actual key in your writeup :) You do need a lawyer's advice on how to better phrase your text.